# Atlassian Jira SVN Plugin Help

Tags: jira

I have installed Jira and the subversion plugin (with success from what i can tell from the administration panel - subv. plugin installed).

I then add a repository that I have created on the file system, BUT i cannot see an option which will link/connect a new or existing project to a SVN repository. What i want to do is link a project with a repository so I can track commits made to the project (link commits with issues). After some searching i found that this is possible but I cannot figure a way to do it.

Do I need another plugin for that? I have tried googling for the last hours but I cannot find anything related.

regards,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way SVN-Jira linking works by default is to simply put the issue identifier of the Jira issue in the comment when committing to the SVN repository.

It can be helpful to enable comment editing in the repository, if you have past commits or users who forget to add comments when committing.

Example commit comment:

- Fixed problem with login. See issue MYJIRAPROJECT-26 in issue tracker.

There's a service in Jira which scans the SVN repository at regular intervals, and builds a cache of any SVN revisions where an issue identifier appears. Depending on the polling interval, it make take a few minutes for the commit to show up in Jira.

Comment: Thank you. You are right..i thought there was a way to link a project with a repo. The 'thing' now is to find out if there are ways to change the SVN polling time. As you might have guessed i a new to Jira and it's 'ecosystem'...i think i read somewhere that this time is close to 1 hr but not sure..

Comment: From the administration page, under the system section, choose "Services". You should see the "Subversion Revision Indexing Service" listed. From here you can edit the index time delay for the service.

Answer (score 4):

The polling time is controlled by the JIRA Service for the SVN plugin. See Admin, Services.

~Matt

Answer (score 2):

you can enforce that future subversion commits require a jira issue reference for more reliable--than relying on your programmer's word ;)--jira-subversion integration

the [jira commit acceptance plugin](https://plugins.atlassian.com/plugin/details/289) can be configured to block commits that don't include a valid (defined by subversion-jira project mapping and/or regular expression as appropriate to your situation) jira issue reference in the commit comment

reliable jira-subversion linkage availability allows handy stuff like:

- [Integration with issue trackers](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/issuetrackers.html)